# Can't build Cassandra 3.11.0 from source code

Tags: git, ant, cassandra

I have cloned Cassandra from github https://github.com/apache/cassandra  and run "git checkout cassandra-3.11.0" "ant artifacts -Dbase.version=3.11.0-1 -Drelease=true".

However I'm getting this error:

```
gen-doc:

BUILD FAILED
/tmp/cassandra/build.xml:260: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "make" (in directory "/tmp/cassandra/doc"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 23 more
```

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you on Linux? It looks `make` isn't installed or isn't available on your path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes,I'm on Linux. I also installed `make`.